# rake test::unit generate unexpected stack of errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I run **rake test:units**
Everything is working fine, but as soon as I added assert false in one of test scenario. I found long stack of error (copied below). Is there a way to get rid of this error?

```
2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib" "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/testtask.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in `verbose'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/testtask.rb:98:in `block in define'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:units
```

Comment: The stack trace is generated by an error raised in `rack` following a test failure. There should be another stack trace higher up which shows the test failure itself. Is your question "what is causing my error?", or is it "how do I get rid of the rack stack trace, so I can see my test failure"?

Comment: You appear to be running `rack` with `--trace` option enabled to get this stack trace? That does make the error message from `rack` a lot more verbose, but won't help you discover why the test has failed.

Comment: thank you Neil, i could see my trace output, and would like to get rid of the rack stack trace . And i run with rake test:units , did not specify --trace